# VB.NET Pass label reference to thread in class

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, collections

hopefully you can either validate my assumption or point me in the right direction.

I'm working on a small GUI to monitor a variable DC power supply. The equipment communicates via a COM port. To do this I have created a Class to handle communicating with the PSU. I would like to implement a method in which the calling form (class) can pass 2 Label references to my PSU class which it can periodically update with voltage and current.

I have already worked out how to update a Label's text from outside the main thread (with Invoke), and I have worked out how to start a second thread running a method with no parameters. From my reading, I can only pass a single parameter to a parameterized thread start.

My current approach is to create a Collection and have the items be those two labels which I mean to pass. The method to create and start the thread accepts (what I think are) pointers to the two labels with the following:

```
Public Sub monitor(ByRef vLbl As Label, ByRef aLbl As Label)
```

Inside that sub (after some error checks and other tasks) I create a new Collection and add the two label references:

```
Dim coll As Collection = New Collection()
coll.Add(vLbl)
coll.Add(aLbl)
```

Which I then pass coll in the thread.Start call.

In the sub actually running on the other thread, I start it by breaking out the two labels:

```
Dim _vLbl As Label = coll(0)
Dim _aLbl As Label = coll(1)
```

Is this a sound approach to the problem? I realize that I could simplify some of this by eliminating the class approach and taking more of a procedural one, but I'm trying to develop my PSU class reference to be used by some other software tools as a library eventually. Please forgive if I have messed up the terminology, I haven't been doing this for long and am trying to teach myself how all of this works.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Grammar Fail

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this isn't how I'd do it, as it violates separation of concerns.  The code that knows how to read the PSU shouldn't need to know what a label is or how to update it.  In the future, you might want to use something other than a label, or may wish to store the numbers in a database as you go, or you might want to use a globalized approach to formatting the number (for example).  If you were ever to make those changes, you shouldn't have to touch the PSU code.

Instead, I would create an object, say, `PSUMonitor`, which does the monitoring.  The PSUMonitor would raise an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) with a custom [EventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) capable of carrying the data you wish to track.

Then, your UI form would subscribe to those events, read the numbers, and then format the information to put them on a label, two labels, a graph, a table, aor whatever else you want.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I kinda figured my approach wasn't the best. In very broad strokes I think I get what you're talking about. I'll try to find some information on how to do this, but I may ask for a bit of a lead if I can't find anything I can understand.

Comment: Found a really good explanation at MSDN, thanks for the tip @John Wu